# Why is org-ql looking for gpg2 in a hardcoded path?

Tags: gpg, org-ql

I'm trying to install org-ql

```
(use-package compat :ensure t)
  
  (use-package org-ql
    :quelpa (org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql"
              :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))

  (use-package helm-org-ql
    :quelpa (helm-org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql"
                         :files ("helm-org-ql.el")))
```

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "/usr/bin/gpg2")
  call-process("/usr/bin/gpg2" nil (t nil) nil "--with-colons" "--list-config")
  epg-config--make-gpg-configuration("/usr/bin/gpg2")
  epg-find-configuration(OpenPGP)
  package-check-signature()
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x15e56f3e5aab311d>)()
  package--with-response-buffer-1("https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x15e56f3e5aab311d>) :file "compat-29.1.4.4.tar" :async nil :error-function #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_79> :noerror nil)
  package-install-from-archive(#s(package-desc :name compat :version (29 1 4 4) :summary "Emacs Lisp Compatibility Library" :reqs ((emacs (24 4)) (seq (2 23))) :kind tar :archive "gnu" :dir nil :extras ((:url . "https://github.com/emacs-compat/compat") (:keywords "lisp" "maint") (:maintainer "Compat Development" . "~pkal/compat-devel@lists.sr.ht") (:authors ("Philip Kaludercic" . "philipk@posteo.net") ("Daniel Mendler" . "mail@daniel-mendler.de")) (:commit . "3809be4d24a301c78d40bd00fc15bb763e0a3a2a")) :signed nil))
  package-download-transaction((#s(package-desc :name compat :version (29 1 4 4) :summary "Emacs Lisp Compatibility Library" :reqs ((emacs (24 4)) (seq (2 23))) :kind tar :archive "gnu" :dir nil :extras ((:url . "https://github.com/emacs-compat/compat") (:keywords "lisp" "maint") (:maintainer "Compat Development" . "~pkal/compat-devel@lists.sr.ht") (:authors ("Philip Kaludercic" . "philipk@posteo.net") ("Daniel Mendler" . "mail@daniel-mendler.de")) (:commit . "3809be4d24a301c78d40bd00fc15bb763e0a3a2a")) :signed nil)))
  package-install-from-buffer()
  package-install-file("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/quelpa/packages/org-super-agen...")
  quelpa-package-install-file("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/quelpa/packages/org-super-agen...")
  quelpa-package-install(org-super-agenda)
  #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_55>((org-super-agenda (1 2)))
  mapc(#<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_55> ((emacs (27 1)) (compat (29 1)) (dash (2 18 1)) (f (0 17 2)) (map (2 1)) (org (9 0)) (org-super-agenda (1 2)) (ov (1 0 6)) (peg (1 0 1)) (s (1 12 0)) (transient (0 1)) (ts (0 2 -1))))
  quelpa-package-install((org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))
  apply(quelpa-package-install (org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))) nil)
  quelpa((org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))
  apply(quelpa (org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))
  (if (and quelpa-use-package-inhibit-loading-quelpa (package-installed-p 'org-ql)) nil (apply 'quelpa '((org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))))
  (unless (and quelpa-use-package-inhibit-loading-quelpa (package-installed-p 'org-ql)) (apply 'quelpa '((org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))))
  (progn (straight-use-package 'org-ql) (unless (and quelpa-use-package-inhibit-loading-quelpa (package-installed-p 'org-ql)) (apply 'quelpa '((org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el")))))) (defvar use-package--warning243 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*use-package*") (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "-----\n" msg "\n\n(use-package org-ql :quelpa\n  (org-ql :fetcher g...") (emacs-lisp-mode)) (setq msg (concat msg " (see the *use-package* buffer)")) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case-unless-debug err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package org-ql") (prog1 (if (not (require 'org-ql nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'org-ql) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package org-ql" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package org-ql"))))) (error (funcall use-package--warning243 :catch err))))
  (use-package org-ql :quelpa (org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el"))))
  (progn (use-package compat :ensure t) (use-package org-ql :quelpa (org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files (:defaults (:exclude "helm-org-ql.el")))) (use-package helm-org-ql :quelpa (helm-org-ql :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/org-ql" :files ("helm-org-ql.el"))))
  org-babel-execute:elisp("(use-package compat :ensure t)\n  \n  (use-package o..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:lexical . "no") (:tangle . "yes")))
  #<subr org-babel-execute-src-block>(nil ("elisp" "(use-package compat :ensure t)\n  \n  (use-package o..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:tangle . "yes") (:lexical . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 176038 "(ref:%s)") nil nil)
  ad-Advice-org-babel-execute-src-block(#<subr org-babel-execute-src-block> nil ("elisp" "(use-package compat :ensure t)\n  \n  (use-package o..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:tangle . "yes") (:lexical . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 176038 "(ref:%s)"))
  apply(ad-Advice-org-babel-execute-src-block #<subr org-babel-execute-src-block> (nil ("elisp" "(use-package compat :ensure t)\n  \n  (use-package o..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:tangle . "yes") (:lexical . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 176038 "(ref:%s)")))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("elisp" "(use-package compat :ensure t)\n  \n  (use-package o..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:tangle . "yes") (:lexical . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 176038 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

It's looking for gpg2, but it seems its path is hardcoded?

I have

```
# which gpg2
/run/current-system/sw/bin/gpg2
```

I'm on NixOS.

EDIT1:

Here's the value of epg-config--program-alist

```
epg-config--program-alist is a variable defined in ‘epg-config.el’.

Its value is
((OpenPGP epg-gpg-program
      ("gpg2" . #1="2.1.6")
      ("gpg"
       ("1.4.3" . "2.0")
       #1#))
 (CMS epg-gpgsm-program
      ("gpgsm" . "2.0.4")))
```

EDIT2:

Indeed, it looks as if epg-gpg-program is set by something, but I don't have any code in my init file which sets this.

I guess I have to do a bisect?

```
epg-gpg-program is a variable defined in ‘epg-config.el’.

Its value is "/usr/bin/gpg2"
Original value was "gpg2"
```

Comment: Check the value of `epg-config--program-alist`: see if it contains a full path (which AFAICT it should not: just the program name should be enough).

Comment: That looks OK. Next step: check the value of `epg-gpg-program`.

Comment: Just do `M-x customize` on the variable and set it back to `gpg2` (the default). That should be enough.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks;). Now what*s the procedure to accept an answer, when yours is just a comment?;)

Comment: There isn't one: I could write an answer but it's not going to be immediate (sometimes there is time and sometimes there isn't: there won't be time in the next few days). You can write your own answer (and accept it - perhaps after a required delay) - however many of your past questions have been answered but are waiting for you to accept the answer: my recommendation is to go through all such questions and see which ones you can accept. It would be good to get as many of them out of the way as possible.

Comment: Yes, I will go through all questions and answer them, but I have to take a few at a time;). There has been some issues with notifications, but it's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `epg-gpg-program` was hardcoded to the path `"/usr/bin/gpg2"`, probably because it was customized previously, so the setting is done in the file specified by the variable `custom-file` (presumably set to something different from the init file, which I think is a good idea, but you have to check the customization file in addition to your init file when things go awry).

Throwing away the customization will set `epg-gpg-program` back to the default which is just `gpg2`, with no path specified. `epg` will then search for an executable named `gpg2`(using `executable-find` which searches every directory specified in `exec-path`) and it will use that (assuming that it finds one). IOW, in most cases there is no reason to customize `epg-gpg-program`.